# Is $\Delta x=\frac 12(v_f+v_i)\Delta t$ considered as a linear function of time when acceleration is constant?

Tags: kinematics

$\Delta x=\frac 12(v_f+v_i)\Delta t$ because its a linear combination it looks like a linear function, however also as time increases acceleration stays the same therefore velocity changes and that makes it look like a quadratic function at the same time, is it a linear function?

Comment: The function is already linear in time if $v_f$ and $v_i$ are assumed to be constant. This equation is to do with the average velocity over time, It doesn't offer much for acceleration, since there is no $\Delta t ^ 2$ terms in the equation.

Comment: @Joshua Pasa, i don't think that vf is constant when acceleration is constant since $v_f=a\Delta t$

Comment: @Zheer Josh said if $v_f$ is *assumed* to be constant which it's not as you already know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation you wrote gives the *average displacement*. It is not linear because $v_f = a\Delta t$ (if $a$ is constant as you said). Average displacement is not the same as *total displacement* and we are typically interested in average velocity instead of average displacement. Both $v_f$ and $\Delta t$ are growing linearly and the *product* of $v_f$ and $\Delta t$ grows quadratically as can be seen below:

Substitute $a \Delta t$ for $v_f$ in your equation to see that $\Delta x_{avg} \propto \Delta t^2$

$\Delta x = \frac{1}{2}(a\Delta t + v_i)\Delta t = \frac{1}{2}[a (\Delta t)^2 + v_i\Delta t]$

It is indeed quadratic.

Note: by me writing $(\Delta t)^2$ I'm assuming that $t_i = 0$

Otherwise, we'd need to write $t_f^2 - t_i^2$

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is a representation of $x$ as a linear combination *of the speeds*. But more practically, you will be considering $t$ to be the independent variable; if the speed $v_f$ depends on time, which it will in any scenario with nonzero acceleration, then one of the terms is itself function of $t$ so you do *not* have $x$ as a linear combination of your independent variable $t$, you have an equation of the form $x=at+f(t)t$ (where the nonlinear term $f(t)t$ will simplify to a quadratic $t^2$ in the case of *constant* acceleration).

2nd update pointing out further relationships:

When $a=0$ (no acceleration), $v(t)=v_0$ (a flat horizontal line indicating constant speed), and $x(t)=x_0+v_0t$ (a line where the slope is the speed, position as a linear function of time). The relationship of these graphs to each other will be clear if you are familiar with calculus. To review the more general case, if the acceleration is constant, $a=a_0$ (a flat horizontal line), $v(t)=v_0+a_0t$ (a line where the slope is acceleration, speed as a linear function of time) and $x(t)=x_0+v_0t+\frac{1}{2}a_0t^2$ (a parabola with vertex at $\frac{-v_0}{a_0}$, position as a quadratic function of time).

Comment: "then one of the terms is a function of t", does that mean it is function inside function?

Comment: @Zheer Yes, it would be $\Delta x \, (v_f(t),t)$ which would ultimately be a quadratic function of $t$ after substituting for $v_f$ as I showed

Comment: @Zheer edited, does that clear everything up for you?

Comment: @electropusher,does that mean that when acceleration is zero it is a linear function but otherwise it isn't linear?

Comment: @Zeer Yes, but then $v_f=v_i$. The velocity is constant and the average displacement becomes equal to the total displacement - but if velocity were constant there'd be no point in using this equation in the first place (although there really *never* is any for the reason I stated in my comment).

Comment: @Zeer You'd get a trivial answer by substituting $v_i$ for $v_f$ that would give you $\Delta x = v_i\Delta t$ which is just the total displacement occurring during $\Delta t $ at a constant velocity

Comment: @Andrew,i have heard that a function can't be both linear and not linear at the same time, how is that possible?

Comment: @Zheer Yes, I updated my answer to point out a few things along those lines.

Comment: @Zheer the fact that $v_f$ is in the equation implies the equation is nonlinear cause otherwise there's no point in distinguishing $v_f$ from $v_i$ notationally. Your question about linearity is a math question & not in the scope of your original question. Normally you'd need to make a new post to ask that in the **Mathematics** stack exchange. I'll make an exception one time - the *definition* of linear & non linear are mutually exclusive - they can't be true for the same function at the same time. https://study.com/academy/lesson/how-to-recognize-linear-functions-vs-non-linear-functions.html